# Buttons are not centering despite being inside a <div align="center"> tag

Tags: visualforce, css

I have 3 buttons I would like to center in the middle of the page, but no matter what tag I wrap them in, they are displaying way off to the left.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false" lightningStylesheets="True">
<apex:slds >
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.portfolio}"/>
    
<style>
    div {
    
    
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 0px;
    }
    
    .container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    
    .centered {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
</style>
<head> 
<title>John Smith</title>
</head>   
<br/>
<div align="center" class="slds-scope">
    <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">John Smith</h1>
        <div class="row" text-align="center">
        <div class="column" align="left">
             <button class="slds-button">Salesforce</button>  
        </div>
        <div class="column" align="center">
             <button class="slds-button">Software</button>  
        </div>
        <div class="column" align="right">
             <button class="slds-button">About Me</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </apex:slds>
</apex:page>
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: I believe this is not a question suitable for the Salesforce Stack Exchange website, because it is not about a Salesforce product or implementation. This is a CSS question, and would probably get more visibility on the general Stack Exchange website.

Comment: I do believe, however, that you can find multiple answers for your problem by searching "how to center a div in a page" and/or related queries on your favourite search engine.

Comment: Have you tried [Absolute Center](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/alignment/#site-main-content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just have a class defined `container`

```
<div class="row centercontainer">
    <div class="column" align="left">
        <button class="slds-button">Salesforce</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column" align="center">
        <button class="slds-button">Software</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column" align="right">
        <button class="slds-button">About Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css as :

```
        .centercontainer {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use flex or grid layout in order to center elements.
You could take advantage of SLDS classes like .slds-grid (for container) and .slds-col (for items) to meet your requirements.
Please take a look [here](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/).
SLDS offers also classes to [align text](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/text/#Align-Center).

Here's the code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false" lightningStylesheets="True">
<apex:slds/>
<div class="slds-scope">
    <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large slds-text-align_center">John Smith</h1>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
        <div class="slds-col slds-m-around_small">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Salesforce</button>  
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-m-around_small">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Software</button>  
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-m-around_small">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">About Me</button>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

With `slds-grid` class you create a [flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/flex_container) and with `slds-grid_align-center` class you set the [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property to `center`.
I added the `slds-m-around_small` class to the flex item in order to give them some [margin](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/margin/).

By the way, you could find [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) very useful.